# Pass Column Data as Query to Power Query in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a sql Select Statement in excel column, I want to pass it as a Query and return data in excel using Power Query.

I have tried this, but it is throwing Expression.SyntaxError: Token Literal expected.

[Query="Select * from Pack.Class where ClassTag='"&'Input Parameters'!C3&"GD"&"' "])

Comment: A couple of questions. 
1. What does a successful query run look like syntax wise?
2. Will you be passing multiple values or just 1 at any given time?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following.
Full connection string is `Sql.Database("serverfdqn", "databasename", [Query = "Sql Code"])`

You may need to input multiple values into your SQL statement.

You have general Power Query knowledge and how to navigate its menus.

If my assumptions are wrong, please notify me and I'll revise my answer.

**Step 1**

Make sure your cell values are in a Table.

[image]

**Step 2**

Import your table into Power Query. Click on your table, then the Data ribbon, then *From Table/Range*

[image]

**Step 3**

Convert your table into a string of text. Your M-Code should look similar to this. You may need to modify the column name. It is also important that the column type be text prior. If your Power Query identified the column as a number, make sure to change it back to text.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Class_Tag_Selection"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Class Tags", type text}}),
    #"Class Tags" = Text.Combine({"'", Text.Combine(#"Changed Type"[Class Tags], "','"), "'"})
in
    #"Class Tags"
```

Your result should look similar to this.

[image]

**Step 4**

Modify your SQL Query to reference your Class tag query.

```
Sql.Database("ServerFDQN", "DatabaseName", [Query = "
SELECT 
    *
FROM Pack.Class
WHERE ClassTag IN ("& Class_Tag_Selection &")
"])
```

The key advantage to this method is that your can modify the table to be any number of items (up to ~1000).

Notes, you will need to change Excel's privacy setting to Ignore. SQL connection won't allow you to insert data from the Excel file.

Inside Power Query, click File, Options and Settings, Query Options, Privacy, Always Ignore.

[image]

[image]